# Deleting same records from same table causes deadlock

Tags: mariadb

We have an table which stores the login information of a company (company will have multiple users), and deletes all the records of the company (all records of that company) when ANY user of that company logins. 
we are receiving the deadlock for the above case, cannot change from application side.
There is no Gap Lock happening, and both delete's are using the proper index.    As it's going for index scan, reading of data should be in sequential order. If it's an sequential order, then the second statement should wait for acquiring lock, but it's causing Deadlock.
MariaDB Version : 10.2.14
Isolation : READ-COMMITTED

```
Below the table DDL
CREATE TABLE `TableA` (
    `TableAKY` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `PERSONKY` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `ID` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `PackageName` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_bin',
    `LOCKEDKY` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `LASTACTIVITYDTTM` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `UPDATEDTTM` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `UPDATEUSER` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'SYSTEM' COLLATE 'utf8_bin',
    `VERSIONSTAMP` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `USERKY` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`TableAKY`),
    INDEX `TableA_GI1` (`LASTACTIVITYDTTM`),
    INDEX `TableA_GI2` (`PERSONKY`),
    INDEX `TableA_GI4` (`LOCKEDKY`),
    INDEX `TableA_GI3` (`ID`, `LASTACTIVITYDTTM`),
    CONSTRAINT `TableA_FK1` FOREIGN KEY (`PERSONKY`) REFERENCES `corperson` (`PERSONKY`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_bin'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

show create table is below

```
CREATE TABLE `TableA` (
`TableAKY` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`PERSONKY` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`ID` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`PackageName` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_bin',
`LOCKEDKY` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`LASTACTIVITYDTTM` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`UPDATEDTTM` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`UPDATEUSER` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'SYSTEM' COLLATE 'utf8_bin',
`VERSIONSTAMP` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`USERKY` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`TableAKY`),
INDEX `TableA_GI1` (`LASTACTIVITYDTTM`),
INDEX `TableA_GI2` (`PERSONKY`),
INDEX `TableA_GI4` (`LOCKEDKY`),
INDEX `TableA_GI3` (`ID`, `LASTACTIVITYDTTM`),
CONSTRAINT `TableA_FK1` FOREIGN KEY (`PERSONKY`) REFERENCES `corperson` (`PERSONKY`),
CONSTRAINT `TableA_CK9` CHECK (`VERSIONSTAMP` >= 0)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=495189 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

Scenario 1 ----------- Deleting different records from same table, but different sessions causing deadlock

```
2019-09-05 11:02:06 140065601476352 [Note] InnoDB: Transactions deadlock detected, dumping detailed information.
2019-09-05 11:02:06 140065601476352 [Note] InnoDB: 
*** (1) TRANSACTION:

TRANSACTION 3665046721, ACTIVE 1 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 5 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 4 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 7139751, OS thread handle 140065636890368, query id 16445911731 <IP of Application 1> appid Updating
delete from TableA where current_timestamp>=lastActivityDtTm and ID=3
2019-09-05 11:02:06 140065601476352 [Note] InnoDB: *** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:

RECORD LOCKS space id 26908 page no 4 n bits 72 index TableA_GI1 of table `DatabaseA`.`TableA` trx id 3665046721 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 4; hex 5d70818e; asc ]p  ;;
 1: len 4; hex 80125384; asc   S ;;

2019-09-05 11:02:06 140065601476352 [Note] InnoDB: *** (2) TRANSACTION:

TRANSACTION 3665046667, ACTIVE 1 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
3 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 2 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 7126671, OS thread handle 140065601476352, query id 16445907427 <IP of Application 2> appid Updating
delete from TableA where current_timestamp>=lastActivityDtTm and ID=229753
2019-09-05 11:02:06 140065601476352 [Note] InnoDB: *** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):

RECORD LOCKS space id 26908 page no 4 n bits 72 index TableA_GI1 of table `DatabaseA`.`TableA` trx id 3665046667 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 4; hex 5d70818e; asc ]p  ;;
 1: len 4; hex 80125384; asc   S ;;

2019-09-05 11:02:06 140065601476352 [Note] InnoDB: (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:

RECORD LOCKS space id 26908 page no 4 n bits 72 index TableA_GI1 of table `DatabaseA`.`TableA` trx id 3665046667 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 3 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 4; hex 5d7081a9; asc ]p  ;;
 1: len 4; hex 80125385; asc   S ;;

2019-09-05 11:02:06 140065601476352 [Note] InnoDB: *** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (2)
```

Scenario 2 ----------- Deleting same records from same table, but different sessions causing deadlock

```
2019-09-06 13:00:11 140064167008000 [Note] InnoDB: Transactions deadlock detected, dumping detailed information.
2019-09-06 13:00:11 140064167008000 [Note] InnoDB: 
*** (1) TRANSACTION:

TRANSACTION 3671781064, ACTIVE 1 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 5 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 4 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 7298913, OS thread handle 140064152139520, query id 16923847059 <IP of Application 2> appid Updating
delete from TableA where current_timestamp>=lastActivityDtTm and ID=1155003
2019-09-06 13:00:11 140064167008000 [Note] InnoDB: *** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:

RECORD LOCKS space id 26908 page no 6 n bits 96 index TableA_GI3 of table `sparkdb`.`TableA` trx id 3671781064 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 4; hex 80119fbb; asc     ;;
 1: len 4; hex 5d71eed4; asc ]q  ;;
 2: len 4; hex 8012590a; asc   Y ;;

2019-09-06 13:00:11 140064167008000 [Note] InnoDB: *** (2) TRANSACTION:

TRANSACTION 3671780157, ACTIVE 15 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
549 lock struct(s), heap size 73936, 66 row lock(s), undo log entries 48
MySQL thread id 7277612, OS thread handle 140064167008000, query id 16923851347 <IP of Application 2> appid Updating
delete from TableA where current_timestamp>=lastActivityDtTm and ID=1155003
2019-09-06 13:00:11 140064167008000 [Note] InnoDB: *** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):

RECORD LOCKS space id 26908 page no 6 n bits 96 index TableA_GI3 of table `sparkdb`.`TableA` trx id 3671780157 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 4; hex 80119fbb; asc     ;;
 1: len 4; hex 5d71eed4; asc ]q  ;;
 2: len 4; hex 8012590a; asc   Y ;;

2019-09-06 13:00:11 140064167008000 [Note] InnoDB: *** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:

RECORD LOCKS space id 26908 page no 6 n bits 96 index TableA_GI3 of table `sparkdb`.`TableA` trx id 3671780157 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 21 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 4; hex 80119fbb; asc     ;;
 1: len 4; hex 5d71ed15; asc ]q  ;;
 2: len 4; hex 801258ff; asc   X ;;

2019-09-06 13:00:11 140064167008000 [Note] InnoDB: *** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)

Am i missing something to consider resolving this deadlock? , please help. Thanks in advance
```

Comment: There is more than just the `DELETE` in the transaction?  If so, show us all the statements in the transaction.

Comment: Also provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Do you have `INDEX(ID, lastActivityDtTm)` -- in that order?

Comment: When user login's fist query triggered is(it delete it own user data) "delete from TableA where personky=1234"   next command to be triggered is (delete all data of that user's company)                                         delete from TableA where current_timestamp>=lastActivityDtTm and ID=3

Comment: show create table is also added